# NodeJS No image returned when trying to convolve image with sharp

Tags: node.js, image

I am trying to apply a sobel filter to my image to detect edges. I don't know what I am doing very well - but I'm experimenting.

I'm trying to add the convolve operator to an image using sharp (https://github.com/lovell/sharp), see below:

```
sharp(body)
    .resize(1000)
    .greyscale()
    .convolve({
        width: 3,
        height: 3,
        kernel: [-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1]
     })
    .webp()
    .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
        res.end(buffer, 'binary');
  });
```

When I add that `.convolve()` operation I don't see any image returned. When I remove it I get the image as usual. I am doing exactly what the documentation seems to be suggesting http://sharp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:** The error I am getting is `[Error: im_local_dmask: nonsense mask parameters]` when I `console.log(err)` just before `res.end()`

Comment: Try adding `on('error', function(err) {   console.log(err);  });` for possible errors.

Comment: Whoops! My bad - ignore previous comment. I am getting an error. The error is `[Error: im_local_dmask: nonsense mask parameters]` Any ideas?

Comment: Im not totally clear on the convolve kernel values but I see that looking at their tests they use positive values which works. Using negative values as they have in the docs which is what you have yields the error. The error is from their C lib indicating invalid values. https://github.com/lovell/sharp/blob/master/test/unit/convolve.js

Comment: Yeah all those tests seem to work on my system. What I don't understand though is why the configuration they detail on their own documentation throws an error. If I can't use negative numbers I'm not sure how I can implement a sobel filter.

Comment: It's only the -2 that yields that error it seems. And it seems to accept a -1 in place

Comment: Yeah - very odd. Still, not sure how to get filter working without the -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was when the values in the kernel added to `0` I needed to add

`scale: 1`

To the kernel object and then everything works fine. Not sure if this is a bug or just misleading documentation. See:

https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/561

---

With the below code everything works fine:

```
sharp(body)
    .resize(1000)
    .greyscale()
    .convolve({
        width: 3,
        height: 3,
        kernel: [-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1],
        scale: 1
     })
    .webp()
    .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
        res.end(buffer, 'binary');
  });
```